# How to serve the Https:// version of your site (via Apache .htaccess) ONLY to devices that support SSL/TLS encryption

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, encryption, tls1.2

I have a *lite* (i.e. slimmed-down / light-weight), "[feature phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_phone)" version of my [primary website](https://www.jamesandersonjr.com/), online at [https://fp.jamesandersonjr.com](https://fp.jamesandersonjr.com/), and I went to test it on the oldest phone I could find, in my house, with at least wi-fi, an old [LG 840G](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/LG-840G_id8020), only to discover the phone doesn't support `https://` protocol!

So, my question is, how to force the `https://` version of a website on *only* the devices that support encryption (SSL/TLS/HTTPS), whereas devices, such as feature phones (like the LG840G), will 'automatically', and 'only' be served the `http://` version of the site?

Achieving this would be awesome, as I'm sure Google knows how to do it.

I need to do this within my 'root' Apache `.htaccess` file as I'm sure that's the most feasible way, to accomplish something like this.

Ok, so I tested the LG-840G, with this page: http://fp.jamesandersonjr.com/php/user_agent_detector.php

Turns out, it's using a browser with Obigo in the user-agent string, so I devised this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(obigo|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(obigo|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It's only supposed to serve the `http:` (non-secure) version to older mobile browsers, without support for `https://`. It's **NOT** supposed to catch modern, 'smart'-phone, browsers too. They can properly handle SSL/TLS/HTTP.

Comment: i don't think apache will know which device supports ssl/https, but YOU can decide which devices do... so https://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-how-to-redirect-users-to-mobile-or-normal-web-site-based-on-device-using-mod_rewrite.
Using device detect you can use the mod_rewrite to redirect in case the device type matches. Google search also returned this: http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/

Comment: @Liquidchrome: That method only works for http connections, not https.

Comment: I doubt there is any *secure* way to do what you are asking. The first thing that happens in HTTPS is the negotiation of the TLS connection, *then* the HTTP protocol starts. If you implement some method to detect when a device doesn't support HTTPS, then almost by definition that method will not be secure, and an attacker will be able (perhaps a man-in-the-middle) will force connections down that route. If you *must* support insecure devices you're best bet is to have a different website, called something like insecure.jamesandersonjr.com, that provides whatever insecure services you must.

Comment: @JamesKPolk How come Google.com can use https:// on my LG-840G but my site can't? are they using old SSL, or the newer TLS? Can I force my https:// site to use what they're using?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing more. What version of Android is your LG-840G running? What does sslabs.com report when you [test your server](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)?

Comment: @JamesKPolk It's a Tracfone so the OS is not name brand. Something ghetto.

Comment: Well, then you can run the ssllabs.com test on google's server and yours and examine the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to figure out which browsers are generally too old to support SSL/TLS/HTTPS properly, and have Apache `.htaccess` 'weed-out' *only* those specific browser types. The rest of the browsers will be forced to use `https://`. Here's the `.htaccess` code, to do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "!(obigo|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(obigo|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Let me know if you find any other browsers that are generally, very old, or are normally handicapped, so I can update the code.